# SQL: Multiple Flight_ID

Tags: sql

I want to write a query that will produce a list each `Flight_ID`, its airport code of origin and destination, start and end time, and then three columns showing the number of seats occupied (rounded up to the nearest whole seat) when the plane is

- 50% full,
- 70% full, and
- 90% full.

This is what I have so far, but it is producing multiple rows for each `Flight_ID` when there should only have one. Any idea why that might be?

```
SELECT Flight_ID, Airport_Code_Origin 'Flying From', 
    Airport_Code_Destination 'Flying to', 
    CONCAT(DATEPART(HH, Departure_DateTime), ':', 
           DATEPART(N, Departure_DateTime)) 'Take Off Time',  
    CONCAT(DATEPART(HH, Arrival_DateTime), ':', 
           DATEPART(N, Arrival_DateTime)) 'Landing Time',
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .5) '50% Capacity', 
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .7) '70% Capacity', 
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .9) '90% Capacity'
FROM Flights f JOIN Aircraft ac
ON f.Carrier_ID = ac.Carrier_ID
```

**UPDATE**

I appreciate the comments. I am new to StackOverflow so I didn't think to provide output data.

Carrier_ID was a FK for both tables and was causing my results to include multiple rows for each Flight_ID. I have a column named Plane_ID that is a PK in ac and a FK in f. I updated the code to join on that column instead and got the results I needed/expected.

```
SELECT Flight_ID, Airport_Code_Origin 'Flying From', 
    Airport_Code_Destination 'Flying to', 
    CONCAT(DATEPART(HH, Departure_DateTime), ':', 
       DATEPART(N, Departure_DateTime)) 'Take Off Time',  
    CONCAT(DATEPART(HH, Arrival_DateTime), ':', 
       DATEPART(N, Arrival_DateTime)) 'Landing Time',
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .5) '50% Capacity', 
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .7) '70% Capacity', 
    CEILING(Number_of_Seats * .9) '90% Capacity'
FROM Flights f JOIN Aircraft ac
ON f.Plane_ID = ac.Plane_ID
```

Comment: You have the wrong `JOIN` condition.  Not really possible to say what the right condition is without sample data.

Comment: provide sample data of input and expected output

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The queries you have shown are invalid standard SQL.